# How to prevent double clicks with ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, double-click

I'm trying to figure out the idiomatic way to prevent a button from being clicked multiple times.

Imagine I have a simple controller action like so ...

```
var FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    go: function() {
        console.log("done!");
    }
  }
});
```

and in my template I have a button defined like so ...

```
<button {{action go}}>Click Me Fast</button>
```

Does the action have an option to disable it immediately / making it so only once true event will be handled by the controller (until it's disabled for example)

**Edit**

I'm looking for a long term / multi use solution. One idea I'm thinking about is creating a special ember-component called "button-disable" that would allow me to create a custom button type that generally disables after a single click -but will still allow me to bubble up events to a parent controller. This feels a little heavier weight than I'd like so if another option exists, or if someone has created an addon for just this - let me know

Comment: Maybe this is what you need. https://github.com/dockyard/ember-cli-async-button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a one-off, if you bind the disabled attribute on your button like so

```
<button {{action go}} {{bind-attr disabled=actionPerformed}}>
```

and then set up your controller like

```
var FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actionPerformed: false,
    actions: {
      go: function() {
        this.set("actionPerformed", true);
        console.log("done!");
    }
  }
});
```

then the button will become disabled after you click it once

If you want a reusable component I'd borrow the spinner button from http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/helpers_and_components/spin_button_for_asynchronous_actions/ and tweak it as you need.

So your JS would be along the lines of

```
window.SpinEg = Ember.Application.create({});

SpinEg.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isLoading:false,
  buttonText:"Submit",
    actions:{
        saveData:function(){
            var self = this;
            var saveTime = Ember.run.later(function(){
                self.set('isLoading', false);

            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});

SpinEg.SpinButtonComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['button'],
  buttonText:"Save",
    isLoading:false,
    actions:{
        showLoading:function(){
            if(!this.get('isLoading')){
                this.set('isLoading', true);
                this.sendAction('action');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The template for your component would be

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' id='components/spin-button'>
    <button {{bind-attr id=id}} {{action 'showLoading'}}>
        {{#if isLoading}}
            <img src="http://i639.photobucket.com/albums/uu116/pksjce/spiffygif_18x18.gif"></img>
        {{else}}
            {{buttonText}}
        {{/if}}
    </button>
</script>
```

and you would then just include the following where you need the button to appear

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' id='application'>
    {{spin-button id="forapplication" isLoading = isLoading buttonText=buttonText  action='saveData'}}
</script>
```

Comment: right on - see the edit above (I'm looking for a reusable solution that can span many buttons across a large project)

Comment: Ah, you added your edit at the same time as I posted :) I've edited my answer to mention the spinner button component from the Ember cookbook. It does basically what you want, the action will only send while the "isLoading" property is false.

Comment: What is wrong with wrapping this solution into an Ember Component?